# Check whether a textbox value is numeric or string

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a (built-in) way in JavaScript to check if a string is a valid number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175739/is-there-a-built-in-way-in-javascript-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-number)

i want to check whether a textbox contains a numeric value or a string using javascript
i used this.

```
var query=getquerystring()
    if(isNaN(query))

        {
           alert("query is a string");
        }
        else{
           alert("query is numeric");

        }
```

where getquerystring() is a function as

```
function getquerystring() {
            var query=document.getElementById("queryString").value;

            return  query;
         }
```

but when i enter a number 1234 in textbox still getting query is a string.
please tell me what is wrong in my code, and suggest me some solution.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:** Looking back at my own answer, I realise the problem with it.  You can't compare with `NaN`, you need to use `isNaN` function:

```
var query=getquerystring();
if(isNaN(parseFloat(query))
{
   alert("query is a string");
}
else{
   alert("query is numeric");
}
```

Or, alternatively, you can use regex pattern matching to see if the string matches what it should.

Comment: if mytestbox value is 1214 or if it is "ring" then too it is displaying "query is numeric"

Comment: Aleks G: I used parseInt