# Jquery textbox value checking

Tags: jquery

How to check the textbox value is string or integer in jquery

```
if ($('#TournamentFee').is(NaN)) {
  alert("String");
} else {
  alert("Int");
}
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/

Comment: A similar answer has been posted here. <br>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466709/check-whether-a-textbox-value-is-numeric-or-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
function isNumber(n) {
    n = n.replace(',','.');
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

var str = $('#TournamentFee').val();

if (!isNumber(str) {
  alert("String");
} else {
  alert("Int");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
$.isNumeric($('#TournamentFee').val())
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AD8PS/)

Using jQuery's [**.isNumeric()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 function checkInput() {
            var input = document.getElementById('textbox').value;
            
            if (!isNaN(input)) {
                alert("Numeric input!");
            } else {
                alert("String input!");
            }
        }
```