# Javascript method to ensure that a date is valid

Tags: javascript, html, function, testing, validation

I'm trying to write a method that checks whether a date is valid. It is passed in three Strings: month, day, and year, in order. Month should be from 0-11 instead of 1-12. I have tested the logic of the code in Java and it works. is_int is another method that tests if a String is composed solely of numerical characters. Unfortunately, I am running into problems which I can't figure out.

```
function is_int(value) {
   for (i = 0 ; i < value.length ; i++) {
      if ((value.charAt(i) < '0') || (value.charAt(i) > '9')) return false
    }
   return true;
}

function isValidDate(value1:String, value2:String, value3:String)
{
  if (!is_int(value3)) return false;
  if (!is_int(value2)) return false;
  if (!is_int(value1)) return false;
  var v1 = parseInt(value1) + 1;
  var v2 = parseInt(value2);
  var v3 = parseInt(value3);
  if (v1 > 12 || v1 < 1) return false;
  if (v2 > 31 || v2 < 1) return false;
  if (v2 == 31) if (v1 == 2 || v1 == 4 || v1 == 6 || v1 == 9 || v1 == 11) return false;
  if (v1 != 2) return true;
  if (v2 < 29) return true;
  if (v2 == 30) return false;
  if (v3 % 400 == 0)
        return true;
  else if (v3 % 100 == 0)
        return false;
  else if (v3 % 4 == 0)
        return true;
  else
        return false; 
}
```

My first tester is something that asks for three text inputs and, if the isValidDate function returns false, displays an alert. If not, it forwards to a blank html page. However, I tried this:

```
function validate() {
  if (!isValidDate("a", "a", "a")) {
  alert("wrong");
  return false;
  }
}
```

and the alert never displayed and it forwarded every time. Strangely enough, this still happened when I removed the exclamation point in front of isValidDate. I also tried swapping the double quotation marks for single, but that didn't fix the problem either. The same thing happens with my tester for is_int. I have no idea where I'm going wrong.

Comment: You can use the built-in function [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) to check whether strings are valid numbers. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175739/is-there-a-built-in-way-in-javascript-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-number/175787#175787

Comment: isNaN is a little different from my function. For example, isNaN("") returns false because "" is equal to 0 according to that function. I don't want "" to be a number so I used mine instead.

Comment: How about `parseInt(some_string, 10) == some_string`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you didn't ask for it, but here's a **much** more valid way to check for dates, and it handles odd dates more consistently:

```
function isValidDate(year, month, day) {
    var d = new Date(parseInt(year,10), parseInt(month, 10)-1, parseInt(day, 10), 0, 0, 0);
    return d.getFullYear() == year &&
           (d.getMonth()+1) == month &&
           d.getDate() == day;
}

isValidDate("2011", "08", "04"); // true
isValidDate("bob", "08", "04"); // false
isValidDate("1979", "1", "1"); // true
```

Fiddle with it: http://jsfiddle.net/2WJCv/

Alternate HTML-only link: http://pastehtml.com/view/b2se2lk9k.html

Comment: jsfiddle isn't working for me (weird proxy problem in my connection) so I can't try your example out (and am too lazy to try it locally), but does it handle non-numeric values? What does `parseInt(month,10)-1` do if month is "test"?

Comment: parseInt(val,10) attempts to convert a string to a number.  If that string is invalid, it returns `NaN`.  The `-1` is because the `Date` constructor requires 0-based months.  Hang on, I'll get you another link to try. (Edit, oops, meant NaN.)

Comment: +1 as this is a good method—only need to test 2 out of 3 conditions at the end though. The extra one doesn't hurt, it's just redundant. Also no need to set the hours, minutes and seconds, but again, doesn't hurt.

Comment: @OverZealous - yeah, I know `parseInt` can return `NaN`, and I know about the 0-based months (I don't understand _why_ they're 0-based, but I know about it). What I was really asking is what is the value of `NaN - 1`, and what happens when you pass that value to the `Date` constructor? Thanks for taking the trouble with the other link.

Comment: `NaN +/- anything` is still `NaN`  It's a bizarro special construct in JS.  Luckily, passing NaN to the Date constructor just returns an "invalid date", where each date part is `NaN`.  Also luckily, `NaN` does not equal anything, so the test still works.

Comment: @nnnnnn - zero based months because javascript copied Java's date object (and defects, e.g. getYear returning two digit year) so that's what it has.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in the isValidDate() function: Should be `function isValidDate(value1, value2, value3)` I got an alert using that.  Hope that helps! :)

Comment: i.e. lose the ":String" at the end of the variables

Comment: Yup, I guess that was my only problem, even though I thought it was actually a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you take the illegal javascript out, it seems to work for me in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ae9aC/.

In your code, I changed this:

```
function isValidDate(value1:String, value2:String, value3:String)
```

to this:

```
function isValidDate(value1, value2, value3)
```

And, the jsFiddle alerts false when passed `isValidDate("a", "a", "a")`.

FYI, there are a lot of ways this function could be improved.  To start with, I would suggest that you change value1, value2 and value3 to month, day, year and similarly v1, v2 and v3 so the function is a lot more self describing.

Also, `parseInt()` should always be passed the radix `parseInt(str, 10)` otherwise it will "guess" the radix based on the contents of the string.

Comment: I didn't think type annotations were standard yet.

Comment: Thanks for your help, especially for the parseInt() tip.

Comment: @joseph - You could vote up the answers you found helpful. That is one of the ideas behind StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Your function declaration is invalid:

```
function isValidDate(value1:String, value2:String, value3:String) {
  // your code here
}
```

JavaScript function parameters and variable declarations don't have types, so you need to say:

```
function isValidDate(value1, value2, value3) {
  // your code here
}
```

(An unrelated suggestion: name your parameters and variables more meaningfully. If you expect month, day, year, why not call them that? Especially when dealing with dates where a lot of countries normally say day, month, year rather than month, day, year.

Another unrelated suggestion: look into regular expressions.)

Comment: Thanks this was a good answer too. I inserted the :String after the variables after doing a cursory Google search to figure out why my method didn't work before. I must have changed something else in between so when my method body finally was correct it still wouldn't run, but I didn't remember changing anything else so I got really confused.

Answer (score 0):

If you like doing it long hand and without using the Date constructor, try:

```
function validDate(y, m, d) {
  // Days in month
  var days = [,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31];
  // Adjust February it's a leap year
  if (m == 2 && (!(y%4) && y%100) || !(y%400)) {
    days[2] = 29;
  }
  // Check date in month
  return d <= days[+m];
}
```

It may be faster, or not. :-)

Comment: I just didn't know about the Date constructor. Thanks for your answer though.