# Adding to Number.MAX_VALUE

Tags: javascript, math, floating-point, infinity

The answer to this question may be painfully obvious but I can't find it in the Mozilla docs nor on Google from a cursory search.

If you have some code like this

```
Number.MAX_VALUE + 1; // Infinity, right?
Number.MIN_VALUE - 1; // -Infinity, right?
```

Then I would expect adding *anything* to Number.MAX_VALUE would push it over to `Infinity`. The result is just `Number.MAX_VALUE` spat right back at me.

However, when playing around in the Chrome JS console, I noticed that it didn't actually become `Infinity` until I added/subtracted enough:

```
Number.MAX_VALUE + Math.pow(100,1000); // now we hit Infinity
Number.MIN_VALUE - Math.pow(100,1000); // -Infinity at last
```

What is the explanation for this "buffer" between `Number.MAX_VALUE` and `Infinity`?

Comment: There are several unintuitive behaviors with big and small numbers- try subtracting Number.MIN_VALUE from Number.MAX_VALUE, for one.

Comment: Number.MIN_VALUE "is the number closest to 0, not the most negative number, that JavaScript can represent" [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MIN_VALUE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MIN_VALUE)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Standardwise...

In ECMAScript, addition of two nonzero finite numbers is implemented as <sub><sup>(ECMA-262 §11.6.3 "Applying the Additive Operators to Numbers")</sup></sub>:

> the sum is computed and **rounded** to the nearest representable value using **IEEE 754 round-to-nearest mode**. If the magnitude is too large to represent, the operation overflows and the result is then an infinity of appropriate sign.

IEEE-754's round-to-nearest mode specifies that <sub><sup>(IEEE-754 2008 §4.3.1 "Rounding-direction attributes to nearest")</sup></sub>

> In the following two rounding-direction attributes, an infinitely precise result with magnitude **at least *b<sup>emax</sup>* ( *b* − ½ *b*<sup>1-*p*</sup> ) shall round to ∞** with no change in sign; here *emax* and *p* are determined by the destination format (see 3.3). With:
>
> - roundTiesToEven, **the floating-point number nearest to the infinitely precise result shall be delivered**; if the two nearest floating-point numbers bracketing an unrepresentable infinitely precise result are equally near, the one with an even least significant digit shall be delivered
> - roundTiesToAway, the floating-point number nearest to the infinitely precise result shall be delivered; if the two nearest floating-point numbers bracketing an unrepresentable infinitely precise result are equally near, the one with larger magnitude shall be delivered.

ECMAScript does not specify which of the round-to-nearest, but it doesn't matter here because both gives the same result. The number in ECMAScript is "double", in which

- *b* = 2
- *emax* = 1023
- *p* = 53,

so the result must be at least 2<sup>1024</sup> - 2<sup>970</sup> ~ 1.797693134862315**8** × 10<sup>308</sup> in order to round to infinity. Otherwise it will just round to MAX_VALUE, because that *is* the closer than Infinity.

Notice that MAX_VALUE = 2<sup>1024</sup> - 2<sup>971</sup>, so you need to add at least 2<sup>971</sup> - 2<sup>970</sup> = 2<sup>970</sup> ~ 9.979202 × 10<sup>291</sup> in order to get infinity. We could check:

```
>>> Number.MAX_VALUE + 9.979201e291
1.7976931348623157e+308
>>> Number.MAX_VALUE + 9.979202e291
Infinity
```

---

Meanwhile, your `Math.pow(100,1000)` ~ 2<sup>6643.9</sup> is well beyond 2<sup>1024</sup> - 2<sup>970</sup>. It *is* already infinity.

Comment: Great explanation straight from IEEE-754! I need to get around to reading that spec...maybe when I have trouble falling asleep.

Comment: @Mark:  I find the IEEE 754 standard to be short and friendly, as standards go.  For dealing with serious insomnia, I recommend reading the Unicode standard instead. :-)

Comment: So round-to-nearest *does* come into it? I feel silly deleting my answer now. ;-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: [Because there's no `<small>`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40035/allow-the-small-tag).

Comment: @kennytm, from the question: _Number.MIN_VALUE - 1; // -Infinity, right?_ - is my understanding correct that this should not be treated as overflow, it's underflow, and should not evaluate to `-Infinity`, but to `0` according to IEEE-754 standard?

Comment: @Maximus: `Number.MIN_VALUE` is `5e-324`, it is the minimum *positive* value. The result is just `-1`.

Answer (score 12):

If you look at `Number.MAX_VALUE.toString(2)`, you'll see that the binary representation of `MAX_VALUE` is 53 ones followed by 971 zeros.  This because IEEE 754 floating points are made of a *mantissa* coefficient multiplied by a power of 2 (so the other half of the floating point number is the *exponent*).  With `MAX_VALUE`, both the mantissa and the exponent are maxed out, so you see a bunch of ones bit-shifted up a lot.

In short, you need to increase `MAX_VALUE` enough to actually affect the mantissa, otherwise your additional value gets lost and rounded out.

`Math.pow(2, 969)` is the lowest power of 2 that will not tip `MAX_VALUE` into `Infinity`.

Comment: +1, was just pointing that out in mine as well. In fact, I think this is the better answer by far.

Comment: Thanks!  (To clarify for future viewers, @T.J. was comparing against his own (now deleted) answer, not against Kenny's new answer, which is quite good.)

Comment: +1 for giving the exact point that "tips" `MAX_VALUE` to `Infinity`.