# jax rs data conversion

Tags: java, json, jackson, jax-rs

I have to return a DTO from service which looks like this:

```
ResponseDTO
{
  Long id;
  String name;
  //getter and setter etc.
}
```

Service returns response in json format, and I am using `org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider` for conversion but at client side when I get response then id value gets changed automatically.

for e.g:- from service side I set value of id as Long.MAX_VALUE but client side json response shows me value "9223372036854776000" which is not the value which I am sending from service.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: So to clarify, you set `ResponseDTO.id = 9223372036854775807` and receive `{ "id": "922337203685477000", ... }`? This seems wrong for several reasons.

Comment: Yes, It seems to be wrong, but happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that Javascript handles all `Number`s as 64-bit IEEE 754 floating point numbers. These can't represent `9223372036854775807` (the value of `Long.MAX_VALUE`) exactly.

That's the reason why [Feature.WRITE_NUMBERS_AS_STRINGS](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.6.2/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/JsonGenerator.Feature.html#WRITE_NUMBERS_AS_STRINGS) exists. You need to enable this feature to receive the actual number. Note that converting this to a `Number` will still result in `9223372036854776000` (round up). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10838069/785663) for how rounding works in Javascript.