# isFinite() in JavaScript producing unexpected result

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript maximum value, a number can have is get from `Number.MAX_VALUE` property. If I console,

```
console.log(isFinite(Number.MAX_VALUE)); // true
```

Getting true is expected. But I am expecting false in below statement as I am adding 1 to maximum value.

```
console.log(isFinite(Number.MAX_VALUE + 1));
```

But it is returning true. What is the reason?

Adding one more case. Following line output false as expected.

```
console.log(isFinite(Number.MAX_VALUE * Number.MAX_VALUE));
```

Question mentioned in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179) explains maximum integer value. But I need to know how a number exceeding maximum float value works.

Comment: Because that's the definition of finite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Number.MAX_VALUE + 1` is not `Infinity`.

You should read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10837670/2505965), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10838069/2505965) for a good explanation.

As for `isFinite`, very simply:

> If the argument is NaN, positive infinity, or negative infinity, this method returns false; otherwise, it returns true.

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite). See also: [`Number.isFinite`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isFinite).