# What is the minimum number I need to add to get Infinity for 1 byte floating point

Tags: javascript, floating-point, ieee-754

I'm trying to understand what minimum number I need to add to get `Infinity` because of overflow. I've read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10837898/2545680) already. So let me just clarify my understanding here. To simplify, I'll be working with 1 byte floating point with 4 bits for exponent and 3 bits for mantissa:

```
0 0000 000
```

The maximum positive number I can store in it is this:

```
0 1110 111
```

which is when converted to scientific notation:

```
   1.111 x 2^{7} = 11110000
```

Is my understanding correct that the minimum number I should add to get `Infinity` is `00010000`:

```
       11110000
+      00010000
        --------
     1 00000000
```

As I understand anything less than `00010000` will not cause overflow and the result will be rounded to `11110000`. But the `00010000` is `0 0000 001` in floating point format, and it's the number `1`. So is adding just `1` enough to cause overflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is given in [the other answer to the question you link to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10838069/392585). The smallest value which will round to infinity is:

*c* = 2<sup>7</sup> × ( 2 − ½ × 2<sup>1-4</sup> ) = 1.9375 × 2<sup>7</sup> = 1.1111<sub>2</sub> × 2<sup>7</sup>

So the smallest value that you can add to get infinity is

*c* − *f*<sub>max</sub> = 1.1111<sub>2</sub> × 2<sup>7</sup> − 1.111<sub>2</sub> × 2<sup>7</sup> = 0.0001<sub>2</sub> × 2<sup>7</sup> = 2<sup>3</sup>

which, if I understand correctly, would have bit pattern `0 1010 000` in your proposed format.

UPDATE: so why is it this particular cutoff?

Suppose that there was another binade above this one, then the next floating point number would be

*x* = 1.000<sub>2</sub> × 2<sup>8</sup>

Note that *c* is the value that is exactly halfway between *x* and *f*<sub>max</sub>. In other words, the values which would round up to *x* are instead rounded to infinity, but the values which would round down to *f*<sub>max</sub> still round to the same value.

Comment: thanks, but the number you calculated `2^3=1000` if added to `1111 0000` will produce `1111 1000`, which doesn't seem to cause overflow, simply the fifth bit is set to 1 and the number will be rounded to max_value. I would expect that overflow to turn entire mantissa to zeros with `1` going over the available bits. Just like for example if you add two 1 byte binary numbers `1111 1111` and `0000 0001` and you get an overflow `1 0000 0000` (9 bits can't be put, so the first 1 is discarded). Is it not so with overflow in floating point?

Comment: what is max_value?

Comment: in my 1 byte floating point it's `0 1110 111`. I'm assuming that when floating point adds two numbers, it converts it from scientific from into plain representation, like `0.001 x 2^2 + 0.011 x 2^1 = 0.1+0.11` and adds them like this, then it converts back to scientific form and to floating point representation. Maybe this is where my confusion mentioned in the previous comment comes from

Comment: I think you're trying to think of it in terms of integer operations: floating point overflow is different than integer overflow. If you want to learn how floating point addition is performed, look at something like this http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~markhill/cs354/Fall2008/notes/flpt.apprec.html

Comment: yeah, mostly I'm trying to understand the rationale behind the formula specified in the answer your linked and the phrase 'you need to increase MAX_VALUE enough to actually affect the mantissa' in the answer I linked to. I was thinking that affecting is mantissa is actually causing a integer like overflow. What's your take on `affecting the mantissa`?

Comment: I think that answer is wrong (or, at the very least, unhelpful). Another way to think about it is how it would round if there was another binade above this one.

Comment: So you would suggest just remember the formula and not bother why it's such?

Comment: I've updated the answer, hopefully that explains it further.

Comment: thanks a lot, I'll go though your explanation and I'll probably get back to you with question :)

Comment: _Suppose that there was another binade above this one_ - can you elaborate a bit? there's not much on _binade_ term on the web

Comment: A binade is a set of all floating point numbers with same exponent, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binade

Comment: yeah, I've seen that one sentence definition, didn't much help. _another binade above this one_ - what are these two numbers?

Comment: In this case, it's the set of floating point numbers with exponent of 2^8