# Javascript Infinity add and multiply

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why is Number.MAX_VALUE+10 = 1.7976931348623157e+308 (the same like Number.MAX_VALUE) but Number.MAX_VALUE*2 = Infinity?

Comment: Downvoters care to comment?

Comment: thx for downvoting but an answer would be more helpful. If I exceed the maximum value for a number I would expect to get Infinity as an answer. Why does it not appear when I add a low number like 10?

Comment: I didn't understand the downvotes also. The question is very relevant.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, we want questions and answers about practical software programming problems. This does not seem to be practical. Also, it's been asked [before](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10837670/215552), which I was able to find as it was the third result when searching for Number.MAX_VALUE...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan well... its seems to me a practical software programming problem. The OP summed numbers and it didn't get the expected result. Practical enough. And about the question you pointed out, it may have a similar answer, but their both different in my view.

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira I'm struggling to see why, in a normal, everyday program, you would be adding 10 to Number.MAX_VALUE, or multiplying it by 2 for that matter. The OP accepted the duplicate, that's why it shows "Community" as the other closer. You're welcome to post a Meta question about the closure, or ask on the [SOCVR chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) for help in reopening if you feel strongly about the closure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript uses [a floating point representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) which has 52 bits available for the fraction, while 11 bits are reserved for the exponent.

The precision of a number is dependent on the exponent. For 1e308 this precision is about 1e292. So anything smaller added to `Number.MAX_VALUE` will not change it. If however you do add something to it that is significant enough to change a bit in the fraction (like 1e292), then the number will change. As there is no larger number than `Number.MAX_VALUE` in this representation, except `Infinity`, the latter is the value you get.

Comment: perfect answer, thank you