# typeof() function errors in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a (built-in) way in JavaScript to check if a string is a valid number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175739/is-there-a-built-in-way-in-javascript-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-number)

I have an input search bar in HTML

```
<form class="form-inline" action="javascript:displayResult()">          
    <input id="searchKey" >
    <button onclick="result()" type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn ">
          Go
    </button>                   
</form>
```

This is the Javascript function

```
function result() {     
    search($('#searchKey').val());    

    if(typeof(searchKey)=="number") { // checking if this is a number
       someFunction();
    }
};
```

The problem is , for each entry to the search bar I get the value as a string , even if it is "hello" or 9789 in the search bar . I used `alert(typeof(searchKey));` to verify and it always return the type as string

I am trying to differentiate between a number and a string at the search bar , I am sure there is a better way to do this , but I am unsure about why this is not working

I cannot use parseInt() as I need to differentiate between text and number dynamically

Comment: When would code after a `return` statement get executed?

Comment: You are calling it after return man!

Comment: apologies , I ave edited my code

Comment: is `searchKey` a global variable?

Comment: try parseInt(str, base) if it fails it should just return 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value of a `<input type="text">` is always a string. You can, however, parse it as an number by using `parseInt`. It will result in `NaN` if not number could be parsed from the string. Don't forget you'll have to use [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) for this, as `myNumber === NaN` isn't a valid operation.

Even better, use `isNaN(+searchKey)`, as the unary operand will call `ToNumber`. However, this will ignore whitespace.

> #### 9.3.1 ToNumber Applied to the String Type
>
> ToNumber applied to Strings applies the following grammar to the input String. If the grammar cannot interpret 
>   the String as an expansion of StringNumericLiteral, then the result of ToNumber is NaN.
>
> [see http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf for the actual rules]

---

> #### 11.4.6 Unary + Operator
>
> The unary + operator converts its operand to Number type. 
>   The production UnaryExpression : + UnaryExpression is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let expr be the result of evaluating UnaryExpression.
> 2. Return ToNumber(GetValue(expr)).

Comment: it' sometimes cannot work . like "123dwabc".

Comment: @blueiur: You could either use `parseInt(val).toString() == val` to make sure that both values are the same or use a [regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11807113/1139697).

Comment: i think use parseFloat insteadof parseInt :)

Answer (score 3):

use

```
if(!isNaN(searchKey))
```

instead of

```
if(typeof(searchKey)=="number")
```

Answer (score 3):

A text input field always contains a `string` value. Try `if (!isNaN(searchKey))` to test for numeric value. Alternatively you could use a Regular Expression: `/^\d+$/.test(searchKey)`