# How to change dropdown by checking user input

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, function, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm currently working on a rails project. I'm creating a text_field and a select_tag. I wish to connect them and change the select_tag value base on the text_field.

For example: 
My drop down list have two options, number and alphabets.
If I input '12345', the drop down box will automatically change to 'number'.
If I input 'hello', the drop down box will automatically change to 'alphabets'.

I'm a newbie with web programing. It would be awesome if someone could also tell me how to use this jquery script in rails too!

Many thanks!!!

Comment: what have you done so far??

Comment: So far I have a text box and a drop down.
<div id = "print_id">
<%= text_field_tag :input_item_id %>
</div>
</td>

<td>
<div id = "print_type">
<%= select_tag :input_id_type, "<option>Numeric Id</option><option>Alphabet Id</option>".html_safe%></div>
</td>
</tr>

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/175787/858840) tells you how to find out if the value is numeric or alphanumeric. Once you know that, you can use jQuery to change the value of your select_tag. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! Hmm but how do you change the value of select_tag with jQuery?