# how to check for datatype in node js- specifically for integer

Tags: javascript, node.js

I tried the following to check for the datatype (specifically for integer), but not working.

```
var i = "5";

if(Number(i) = 'NaN')
{
 console.log('This is not number'));
}
```

Comment: have u tried isNan? possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175739/is-there-a-built-in-way-in-javascript-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-number

Comment: If you only except integers you can use [`Number.isInteger`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isinteger.asp)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I think of two ways to test for the type of a value:

**Method 1:**

You can use the `isNaN` javascript method, which determines if a value is [NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) or not. But because in your case you are testing a numerical value converted to string, Javascript is trying to guess the type of the value and converts it to the number 5 which is not `NaN`. That's why if you `console.log` out the result, you will be surprised that the code:

```
if (isNaN(i)) {
    console.log('This is not number');
}
```

will not return anything. For this reason a better alternative would be the method 2.

**Method 2:**

You may use javascript [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) method to test the type of a variable or value

```
if (typeof i != "number") {
    console.log('This is not number');
}
```

Notice that i'm using double equal operator, because in this case the type of the value is a string but Javascript internally will convert to Number.

A more robust method to force the value to numerical type is to use [Number.isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN#Browser_compatibility) which is part of new Ecmascript 6 (Harmony) proposal, hence not widespread and fully supported by different vendors.

Comment: Even better `typeof i != "number"`.

Answer (score 7):

i have used it in this way and its working fine

```
quantity=prompt("Please enter the quantity","1");
quantity=parseInt(quantity);
if (!isNaN( quantity ))
{
    totalAmount=itemPrice*quantity;

}
return totalAmount;
```

Comment: +1 for putting a return statement right in the middle of a if/else clause. cuz, who needs language rules, right? ANARCHY!

Comment: dont use `parseInt`, `123abc` kinds of values will be parsed to 123

Answer (score 4):

I just made some tests in node.js v4.2.4 (but this is true in any javascript implementation):

```
> typeof NaN
'number'
> isNaN(NaN)
true
> isNaN("hello")
true
```

the surprise is the first one as type of NaN is "number", but that is how it is defined in javascript.

So the next test brings up unexpected result

```
> typeof Number("hello")
"number"
```

because Number("hello") is NaN

The following function makes results as expected:

```
function isNumeric(n){
  return (typeof n == "number" && !isNaN(n));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is correct but you have 2 mistakes apparently everyone missed:

just change `if(Number(i) = 'NaN')` to `if(Number(i) == NaN)`

`NaN` is a constant and you should use **double** equality signs to compare, a single one is used to assign values to variables.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one `isNaN(Number(x))`
where x is any thing like string or number

Answer (score 1):

You can check your numbers by checking their constructor.

```
var i = "5";

if( i.constructor !== Number )
{
 console.log('This is not number'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if "1" ou 1 can be casted to a number, you can use this code :

```
if (isNaN(i*1)) {
     console.log('i is not a number'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var val = ... //the value you want to check
if(Number.isNaN(Number(val))){
  console.log("This is NOT a number!");
}else{
  console.log("This IS a number!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use node 12, you can use

```
Number.isInteger(..)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger