# Type of HTML element returned from document.getElementById String not Number

Tags: javascript

I am obtaining the value of an HTML element by using document.getElementById.innerHTML, and then passing that value to a function that returns the type of the value. I am then using an if / else if block to print out the type of value to the console. My problem, is that the typeof method always returns a type of string. If I don't use document.getElementById and declare the variable directly, typeof returns the correct type. Thanks for your help!

JS Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/sY7uW/

```
// get innerhtml of div
var LowTemperature = document.getElementById('LowTemperature').innerHTML;

// check type from function return
if(check_type(LowTemperature) === 'number') {
    console.log(LowTemperature + " is a number");
}
else if(check_type(LowTemperature) === 'string') {
    console.log(LowTemperature + " is a string");
}

// return var type
function check_type(value) {
    return typeof value;    
}
```

Comment: `innerHTML` will *always* return you a string.

Comment: You can try using `isNaN` to detect if it's a number.  If `isNaN(LowTemperature)` returns `false` then `LowTemperature` is a numeric string.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/175739

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to parse the value as an integer, and then compare this back to the original:

```
if(parseInt(LowTemperature) == LowTemperature) alert("LowTemperature is an integer");
```

Comment: Thanks Adam! Works as desired.

Answer (score 2):

innerHTML will only return a string. You will need to parse that to an integer.

[How do I convert a string into an integer in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-an-integer-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is that you're checking the type of number, which exists in string form.  Try this instead:

```
// return var type
function check_type(value) {
    //you could also use parseInt or parseFloat here, but that would return a number for a string like "2014 asdf".  
    //By multiplying by 1, the value will be changed into a number if it is one
    var valueNumber = value*1;
    return typeof valueNumber;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var LowTemperature = document.getElementById('LowTemperature').value;
```

or

```
var LowTemperature = parseInt(document.getElementById('LowTemperature').innerHTML);
```