# Want to validate numeric textbox onclick of submit button

Tags: jquery, validation

Hi guys i m new to jquery and got stuck at a point ,i need ur help to Validate the textbox that only accept the numerics value on onclick function of the submit button

Here is the jquery code

```
<script>
function validate()
 {
   var number=$('#number').val();
   if(number=="")
  {
   alert("only number");
   return false;
  }
 }
```

and html

```
  <input type="text" id="number"value="" />
  <input type="submit" onclick="return validate();"/>
```

Comment: What is not working about what you have tried? If you are asking how to check if a value is a valid number, that question [already has an answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175739/is-there-a-built-in-way-in-javascript-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-number).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just parse as number and check if It's number:

```
function validate()
{
   var number = $('#number').val();
   var cnumber = parseFloat(number);

   if(isNaN(cnumber))
   {
    alert("only number");
    return false;
   }
   return true;
 }
```

Or just:

```
function validate()
{
   var number = $('#number').val();

   if(isNaN(number))
   {
    alert("only number");
    return false;
   }
   return true;
 }
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/fals/Lbq9td9j/

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery you can do:

```
 var currentValue = $(obj).val();
     if($.isNumeric(currentValue)){.....
```