# How does "+var === +var" work internally to verify if var is numeric?

Tags: javascript, string, validation, numbers

Seeing this question: [Is there a (built-in) way in JavaScript to check if a string is a valid number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175739/is-there-a-built-in-way-in-javascript-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-number) and this: [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/isnan-vs-typeof/5), one of the presented approaches is this (mutatis mutandis):

```
var a = "123"
var b = "123b"

if ( +a === +a ) // true

if ( +b === +b ) // false
```

How does this logic work *internally* in JavaScript to make this possible?

My question is **not** how to check if a string is a valid number – this is already answered here: [Validate decimal numbers in JavaScript - IsNumeric()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-decimal-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric). I want to understand how the statement `+a === +a` works.

Comment: It's a magic of `NaN`. But I would use `isNaN(+a)` for this

Comment: [It's all in the spec](http://es5.github.io/).

Comment: The core logic here is that `NaN !== NaN`

Comment: Seeing the huge speed of this in Chrome in the jsperf I'm ready to double-bet that V8 optimizes the test to not even have to run it!

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`+` converts the value to a number.

`a` gets converted to `123` and `123 === 123`.

`b` gets converted to `NaN` but `NaN !== NaN` (because `NaN` is never equal to another `NaN` according [step 4a of the equality rules](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6)).

Comment: It's worth noting that that particular quirk (`NaN != NaN`) is inherited from the IEEE 754 standard for floating point numbers, and so actually holds for most languages.

Answer (score 16):

The `+` operator here is known as the [*Unary Plus*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_(.2B)).

> The unary plus operator precedes its operand and evaluates to its operand but attempts to converts it into a number, if it isn't already.

`+"123"` evaulates as `123`.

```
+a === +a
-> +"123" === +"123"
  -> 123 === 123
    -> true
```

`+"123b"` evaluates as [`NaN` (Not a Number)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN), as the `b` character cannot be converted with the Unary Plus as without any prefix (like `0x` for hexadecimal) the Unary Plus will assume the value is decimal (0-9). `NaN` is a special case in that it does not compare against anything, including itself:

```
NaN === NaN
-> false

NaN !== NaN
-> true
```

Because of this, our `+b` test case fails:

```
+b === +b
-> +"123b" === +"123b"
  -> NaN === NaN
    -> false
```

If you want both to evaluate to true we can add an `isNaN()` call at the end:

```
if ( +a === +a || isNaN(+a) )

if ( +b === +b || isNaN(+b) )
```

Comment: Is `+a === +a || isNaN(+a)` not always true?

Answer (score 6):

`+"123b"` is `NaN`. [NaN is not equal to anything, including NaN.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript/523647#523647)

Answer (score 0):

The two variables are string, but **javascript** convert automatically any string to a number when you **+** or **-** .

```
var a = "1";
var b = a;     // b = "1": a string
var c = +a;    // c = 1: a number
var d = -a;    // d = -1: a number
```

and Basically in your example you try to do this:

```
if ( +"123" === +"123" )  => ( 123 === 123) // true
if ( +"123b" === +"123b" ) => (NaN === NaN) // false
```