# How does “+var === +var” type is number even if we use it in number string

Tags: javascript, type-conversion, logic

Based on this question [How does “+var === +var” work internally to verify if var is numeric?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30192893/how-does-var-var-work-internally-to-verify-if-var-is-numeric/30306462#30306462) :

```
var a = "123"
var b = "123b"
if ( +a === +a ) // true
if ( +b === +b ) // false
```

my question is how if javascript can't convert **"123b"** to a number, the Value would be **NaN**
so how is `typeof +b` // Returns number`

How does this logic work.

Comment: NaN is not a number and also not a value at all. Hence it can't be equal to anything. The type of +b EXPRESSION is number because the plus sign forces the coercion to that type. Even it's holding VALUE is actually not a (valid)  number.

Comment: @bitifet: You might have already read the duplicate question, but for others just passing by here and reading this comment: `NaN` actually **is** a number value. That's why `typeof NaN` returns `"number"`. It's not equal to anything, because that's what the IEEE 754 standard dictates and what JS implements: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3

Comment: according to ECMAScript http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6, given `x === y`, part 4.a.,b.: if `x` or `y` is `NaN`, return `false`.