# Clarification on JavaScript function to validate the Numeric

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am working on an existing function to validate the Object value is numeric and accept only COMMA Character.

Obj = 1,2,3,4,

However function is not giving any results ..

```
var checkOK;
                if (isInt == true) {
                    checkOK = "0123456789";
                }
                else {
                    checkOK = "0123456789.";
                }


                for (i = 0; i < checkStr.value.length; i++) {
                    ch = checkStr.value.charAt(i);

                    for (j = 0; j < checkOK.length; j++) {


                        if (ch == checkOK.charAt(j)) {
                            if (isInt == true && j == 0) {
                                allValid = false;
                                break;
                            }
                            else {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (j == checkOK.length - 1) {
                            allValid = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    allNum += ch;
                }

if (allValid==false)
                {
                    alertsay = "Please enter only valid values "
                    alert(alertsay);
                    document.getElementById(obj.id).innerText="";
                    obj.focus();
                    return (false);
                }
```

Comment: Please elaborate. Do you need to skip the comma or reject the comma?

Comment: Why aren't you using REGEX instead of all this huge code?

Comment: Its a legacy code , application ..

Comment: i can use regex .. if i have to change only in javascript . i am not supposed to change in .Net side ..

Comment: what you are showing ***is*** javascript...so what does `.NET` have to do with anything?

Comment: js function is called onblur event of asp.net text box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript you can do:

```
/^[0-9,]+$/g.test(checkStr);
```

This returns true if a STRING (not object) only contains numbers or numbers + comma at random places. (also returns true for string '123,,6'). Otherwise returns false.

If you want to check is the STRING is a number, with only 1 decimal point or comma, you can do:

```
!isNaN(checkStr);
```

This returns true if checkStr is or can be converted to a valid number.
(from this post: [Is there a (built-in) way in JavaScript to check if a string is a valid number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175739/is-there-a-built-in-way-in-javascript-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-number))