# making variable a number

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I have a text box that I want a person to add a number, and only a number into.  How would I make a function that, if the value added to the text box was not a number, they would get an alert that said, "must add a number", or something similar.  without using RegEx!

thanks!

Comment: Have you tried looking at regular expressions?

Comment: Why not using regex?

Comment: Use <input type="number">. I think it's only solution w/o programming.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175739/is-there-a-built-in-way-in-javascript-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-number

Comment: do you want to perform this check when they submit the form, or when they're entering text? I'm using jquery for something similar, when the user clicks the submit button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp

You want to use `type="number"` on your input field

```html
Type a number:
<input type="number"/>
```

Comment: And if you want to include decimal, you can use step="0.01", or step="any"

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that you can use to only allow the user to enter numbers, they can´t add anything that´s not a number

```html
<HTML>
   <HEAD>
   <SCRIPT language=Javascript>
      function isNumberKey(evt)
      {
         var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
         if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
            return false;

         return true;
      }
   </SCRIPT>
   </HEAD>
   <BODY>
      <INPUT id="txtChar" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" type="text" name="txtChar">
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: what does charCode check? did you get this from somewhere? thanks

Comment: The charCode property returns the Unicode character code of the key that triggered the onkeypress event.

Comment: you might need to check keypad numbers (probably not), and i think mac and windows might have slightly different codes for 0 too

Comment: @neaumusic this works on PC and Mac and so does 0 just tried.

Comment: alright sorry for bothering you then, you could also use `!isNaN(Number(inputValue))`