# Allow numbers and minus sign only

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to allow numbers and a minus sign only in a `input type="text"`. I was able to allow numbers only, but I can't allow the minus sign. I tried the following regular expression to allow numbers only:

```
/\D/
```

When I add the minus sign, it doesn't seem to work:

```
/-?\D/
```

(The reason I have the question mark (?) is because there won't always be a minus sign.) When I try adding a minus sign to the textfield, it doesn't work. Here's the code:

(I tried adding a code snippet, but it wouldn't compile correctly.)

#### CodePen

```
<input id="num" type="text" />

var input = document.getElementById('num');
input.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
    var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (/-?\D/.test(String.fromCharCode(keycode))) { // a non–digit was entered
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: `\D` means anything _but_ numbers. It doesn’t make sense to use it to allow _only_ numbers.

Comment: You want this: `/-?\d+/`

Comment: You can also check the keycode: `keycode >= 48 && keycode <= 59 || keycode == 189`

Comment: I am laughing so hard, @Jessica. Nobody seems to get that you really meant \D, since your code _disallows_ everything what is _not a number_ Literally nobody cared enough to read the line below, nor your //comment.

Comment: Use character class:  /[0-9\-]/ for allow numbres and digits only and /[^0-9\-]/ for inverse

Comment: @KiraCrafter The `-` character may not require escaping within class

Comment: @KiraCrafter Your answer is the only one that actually worked! Just 2 pointers. 1 - How can I limit - to only be the first char? 2 - How can I make 0 not be the first **number** if it's not the only number? For example, say the user typed `02`. I want to remove the 0.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using this regex to **match a valid number**:

```
/^[+-]?\d+$/
```

and having you logic reversed in `test` method as this:

```
var input = document.getElementById('num');
input.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    if (!/^[+-]?\d+$/.test(this.value)) { // a non–digit was entered
    console.log("non-digit was entered");
    $('#num').val('');
    }
});
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/adYRdg?editors=1010)

Comment: I tried that, but I still can't insert the minus sign.

Comment: I think you need to use `blur` in `addEventListener` rather than `keypress`

Comment: How will that help me be able to insert a minus sign?

Comment: The code is still not good as you can enter the minus sign multiple times like `-------78`

Comment: No, `^[+-]?\d+$` will not allow multiple minus signs at start.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `pattern` attribute with `RegExp` `[0-9-]+`

```js
var input = document.querySelector("input");
input.oninput = function(e) {
  if (!this.checkValidity()) {
    // do stuff
    console.log("invalid input")
  }
}
```

```css
input:invalid + label[for="num"]:before {
  content: "invalid input";
}
```

```html
<input id="num" type="text" pattern="[0-9-]+" minlength="1" placeholder="requires input" required /><label for="num"></label>
```

Comment: try your own demo and enter: `123`

Comment: @dev-null See updated post, added `+` following `\d`

Comment: Now try your own demo and enter: `-123` :-)

Comment: @dev-null See updated post. Updated `RegExp` to `-|\d|-\d+|\d+|\d+-`

Comment: BTW, you just need: `-?\d*` or `-?\d+` depending on weather or not `-` is an allowed input.

Comment: @dev-null Yes `RegExp` could probably certainly be shortened ; attempt was to be specific given initial `RegExp` did not return expected results

Comment: @dev-null Actually, current pattern does not return expected results if input is `123-123` , attempting to correct presently. Also, suggested `RegExp`s at comment do not return expected result

Comment: That is correct, but neither would yours. But `-\d+` wont match `123-` either while your part `\d+-` will. I assume OP is interested in detecting positive and negative integers and not ranges, etc... If OP actually want to only allow digits and dashes then you can use a character class: `[-\d]+`

Answer (score 1):

I think this code allow you to only input numbers and minus sign.
But because the code also allow "ctrl + c", "ctrl + v", "ctrl + a", etc..,
The textfield can be input other characters by "ctrl + v"(paste).

If you want to block "ctrl + v"(paste) also, comment out the code below.

```js
$("#num").on("keydown", function(e){
  
  //character, not with ctrl, alt key
  if(e.keyCode >= 65 && e.keyCode <= 90 && !e.ctrlKey && !e.altKey) {
    return false;
  }

  // number with shift
  if(e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57 && !!e.shiftKey) {
    return false;
  }
  
  // ` ~ - _ = + \ | [ { ] } ' " ; : / ? , < . >
  var otherKeys = [186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 219, 220, 221, 222];
  if(otherKeys.indexOf(e.keyCode) !== -1) {
  
    // allow minus sign
    if(e.keyCode === 189 && !e.shiftKey) {
      return true;
    }
    
    return false;
  }
  
  // if you want to block "ctrl + v"(paste), comment the below code out
  //if(e.keyCode === 86 && !!e.ctrlKey) {
  // return false;
  //}

  return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`\D` refers to non-digits

You were probably thinking of `\d`

```
/^-?\d+$/
```

Comment: I tried that, but I still can't insert the minus sign.

Answer (score 0):

You are testing against the result of `String.fromCharCode(keycode)`.

This can never be two characters.

```
if (! /-|\d/.test(String.fromCharCode(keycode))) { // a non–digit was entered
```

The regex `/-|\d/` checks for exactly one character to be either either `-` or a digit.

For use in your code example the result of the match is negated with `!`.

As you are testing every single keypress, this will still allow the input to contain `-` the middle of the value like `123-456-789`.

Answer (score 0):

After reading all of the suggestions, I'd like you to consider a different approach.

### Reason

Your code right now disallows user to modify already inserted input in *any* way with a keyboard. Pressing backspace or delete won't work. Arrows won't work. This does hardly seem as comfortable thing for user.

### Suggestion

Consider this example:

```
var last = '';
var input = document.getElementById('num');
input.addEventListener('input', function(e){
    if (isNaN(e.target.value))
        e.target.value=last;
    else
        last=e.target.value;
});
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/kecer/pen/LGdXLz?editors=1010)

### Explanation

Hooking to event **input** will allow you to look at the new value of your input field. You can check, if it is a number (this also includes floats and negative numbers) by using method **isNaN**, which takes string and returns true if the input is not a number, false otherwise. Therefore, if the condition is true (=not a number), you replace the new value with the last correct one (in this case, default was set to '', but could be something like `var last = isNaN(e.target.value)?'':e.target.value;` (for supporting default values or whatever). Otherwise (the input is indeed a number), you leave the value as it is and record it as last successful.

Benefits are obvious, user is allowed to use keys like arrows, backspace, delete or combinations ctrl+c, ctrl+v, while preserving functionality (wrong input (NaN) is immediately deleted).

### Note

If you want strictly signed integers, with this approach you can always cut off floating point if you detect it in else clause. Plus, not only isNaN considers . (dot, but not a comma) to be valid part of a number, it also allows notations like 1e3. Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/175787/3497425) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I wanted to allow only digits and only a leading minus sign, to avoid things like `----89` or `-89-0-66`, or empty spaces, or dots, as I needed an integer

Obviously, I wanted to allow arrow keys and the delete key as well to edit the input value if needed

My 5 min working solution with jQuery:

`<input id="input" type="text">`

```
var input = $('input');
var allowed = [
 37, //left arrow
 39, //right arrow
 8 //delete
];

input.on('keyup', function(e) {

 if (allowed.indexOf(e.keyCode) !== -1) {
   return;
 }

 //remove white spaces and dots as I want integers
 var value = $(this).val().trim().replace(/\./g, '');

 if (isNaN(value)) {

   //check negative number validation
   if (value.substring(0, 1) === '-') {
     value = value.replace(/\D/g, '');
     value = '-' + value;
   } else {
     value = value.replace(/\D/g, '');
   }
 }
 $(this).val(value)
});
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/mirko77/pen/grBPpr)

The only thing I noticed is when editing on Chrome, the cursor gets at the end of the value after inserting a digit halfway through, it does not happen in Firefox...

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#id").keypress(function(e){
  if (e.which != 46 && e.which != 45 && e.which != 46 &&
    !(e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57)) {
       return false;
    }
});
```

this may help you

Answer (score 0):

by given below code you can achieve that. given code allow minus (-) sign only on first place.

```
<pre><code>
 window.onload=function() {
    var input = document.getElementById("TextBoxId");

    input.onkeypress = function(e) {    e = e || window.event;
        var charCode = (typeof e.which == "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode;

        // Allow non-printable keys
        if (!charCode || charCode == 8 /* Backspace */ ) {
            return;
        }

        var typedChar = String.fromCharCode(charCode);

        // Allow numeric characters
        if (/\d/.test(typedChar)) {
            return;
        }

        // Allow the minus sign (-) if the user enters it first
        if (typedChar == "-" && this.value == "") {
            return;
        }

        // In all other cases, suppress the event
        return false;
    };
    }



</code></pre>
```