# Javascript validation in rows of table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, ag-grid

I am working on ag-grid where I am validating a row. So the column name is Index and here is the validation function I am using.

```
 function numberValidate(params) {
        var new_number = parseFloat(params.newValue);
        if (isNaN(new_number)) {
            window.alert("Invalid value " + params.newValue + ", must be a number");
        } else {
            params.data.index= new_number;
            params.api.onNewRows();

        }
    }
```

If I edit a row and type any value, the variable `new_number` will get that value. It will check if it is numerical; if it is not, it will give a `window.alert`.

If its a number, it will update that row with that value.

My problem is this-->
If I mention '56sfdfd', it takes 56 and updates in the row. However, it should display `window.alert` stating that '56sfdfd' is not a number.

Any idea how to correct this in my Javascript function above. Any inputs appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
var new_number = Number(params.newValue);
```

Find more about this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175739/is-there-a-built-in-way-in-javascript-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-number).