# If var isnumber, for script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I need to run a script which contains the logic: If isNumber, Then DoSomething.

I've run other such *if then* tests such as if blank, and if cell contains "x". It should be simple but I can't find a solution. I've tried getNumberFormat, innum, isnumber, etc.

```js
function ifIsNumber() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = ss.getActiveSheet();

var substring1 = s.getRange("A1").getNumberFormat();

s.getRange("B1").setValue(substring1);

}
```

This code checks cell A1 and returns in cell B1 the string "0.###############", for both cells containing numbers AND text. How can I identify which cells are numbers?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This will check if A1 is a number:

```
function ifIsNumber() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var substring1 = s.getRange("A1").getValue();
    if (!isNaN(parseFloat(substring1)) && isFinite(substring1)) {
        s.getRange("B1").setValue("Is a number");
    } else {
        s.getRange("B1").setValue("Not a number");
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! I'm a bit surprised they've not implemented such a go-to Excel feature. Thank you @Ed!

Comment: ISNUMBER() is already a built in formula in Google Sheets. Just as per Excel. https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093296?hl=en

Answer (score 12):

Google Apps Script could use most of the JavaScript methods and operators.

One alternative to check if an object is a number is to use [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

The following code will return the type of the value of the cell specified by the reference.

```js
function typeofcellvalue(reference) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var rng = ss.getRange(reference);
  var value = rng.getValue();
  return typeof value;
}
```

Example of use as a custom function

```
=typeofcellvalue("A1")
```

If cell `A1`

- has a number, the result will be `number`.
- is empty, the result will be `string`.

Comment: This answer is better because it works with different language settings, i.e. for countries with comma between decimal and integer parts of number. For dates it will returns 'object', for images (formula `Image`) it gives 'string', but I expected 'object'. Hyperlinks are also strings.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do number stuff if the value is a number or a string representation of a number you can do the following:

```
if (!isNaN(myVar)){//myVar is either a number or a string representing a number
    myNumericVar = +myVar;//convert myVar to number if necessary
    //do number stuff
} else {
   //do non-numeric stuff
}
```

See:

[(Built-in) way in JavaScript to check if a string is a valid number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175739/built-in-way-in-javascript-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-number)