# Different alignment for different types of data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, alignment

Is there any possibility to configure a specific range of cells in Google Sheets to:

1. If they are filled by text, the text is aligned to the center?
2. If they are filled by numbers, numbers are aligned to the right?

The default setting is: numbers to the right, text to the left, but can I change it in any way?

Comment: if possible then only via script

Comment: It is possible, I recommend you to take a look at the [Range Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range), the [onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger, the [setHorizontalAlignment method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sethorizontalalignmentalignment) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35252684/if-var-isnumber-for-script) answer regarding the numeric values.

Answer (score -1):

Here you go -

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var value = range.getValue();
  if (!isNaN(value)) {
    range.setHorizontalAlignment("right");
  } else {
    range.setHorizontalAlignment("center");
  }
}
```

Note that this script checks if the value is either a number or not a number and based on that, sets up the alignment.

Hope this helps!