# Why is my function returning true when a string is passed?

Tags: javascript

I have created a function that checks if the argument that is passed is an integer or a float. But for some reason it keeps on returning true when I pass in a string. I don't understand how this happening??

If anyone can help me figure this out I would really appreciate it

```
function isNumeric(val){

    var patt =  new RegExp('^[0-9]+$');

    return (patt.test(val) || Math.floor(val) !== val);



}


console.log(isNumeric("Hello")); //Returns true??
```

Comment: `Math.floor(val) !== val` results in `NaN !== "Hello"` which is `true`; with the correct result from `patt.test(val)` (`false`) you get `return false || true;` which is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can reference the fiddle below. The regex pattern is successful, but the Math.floor() evaluation is problematic.

https://jsfiddle.net/joedonahue/8uw0cr4y/1/

```
function isNumeric(val){
    var patt =  new RegExp('^[0-9]+$');
    return (patt.test(val));
    //return Math.floor(val) !== val;
}
alert(isNumeric("Hello")); //Returns true??
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass in a string, you have the following expression:

```
patt.test("Hello") || Math.floor("Hello") !== "Hello"
```

which then becomes:

```
false || NaN !== "Hello"
```

which then becomes:

```
false || true
```

Since `||` returns a truthy value if either of its arguments is truthy, this returns `true`.

See [Is there a (built-in) way in JavaScript to check if a string is a valid number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175739/is-there-a-built-in-way-in-javascript-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-number) for how to perform your check properly.