# TypeScript isNaN only accepts a number

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webstorm

I work with WebStorm 2016.2.2, TypeScript 2.1, Node.js.

For some reason, `isNaN` is declared as a function that only accepts a number:

```
declare function isNaN(number: number): boolean;
```

I tried to change it to any, but it looks like it doesn't influence on the TSC. I still get the same error:

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'number'

My code (simplified):

```
isNaN("10");
```

How can I solve/workaround it?

---

**Edit:**

Notice that according to specification, isNaN's parameter can be any type: [Number.isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN)

Also: My code was simplified. I actually receive a parameter that may be either a string or a number, and if it's a string it may be either a stringy number that I would like to convert to number ("10") or a simple string ("Hello world").

I didn't want to make this question long by including my entire code, but because it caused confusion, this is my real code:

```
            if (typeof expectedValue === "string" && !isNaN(expectedValue)) {
                    expectedValue = +expectedValue;
                }

            if (typeof actualValue === "string" && !isNaN(ctualValue)) {
                actualValue = +actualValue;
            }

            switch (this.operator) {
                case Operator.equal:
                    return actualValue == expectedValue;
                case Operator.notEqual:
                    return actualValue === undefined || actualValue != expectedValue;
                case Operator.greaterThan:
                    return actualValue > expectedValue;
                case Operator.littleThan:
                    return actualValue < expectedValue;
                case Operator.greaterOrEqual:
                    return actualValue >= expectedValue;
                case Operator.littleOrEqual:
                    return actualValue <= expectedValue;
            }
```

Comment: (1) Why would you need to check if a string is not a number? It's pretty clear that it's not. (2) How did you try to change it?

Comment: You typically are going to pass an expression to `isNaN()` to see if the expression results in a number or not. Passing a literal is a bit unnecessary, don't you think?

Comment: @NitzanTomer I don't really check if a literal is Nan, I simplified my code. Anyway isNan is supposed to accept any type according to the specification.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I don't really check if a literal is Nan, I simplified my code. Anyway isNan is supposed to accept any type according to the specification.

Comment: But if you're using typescript then how do you find yourself in a situation where you pass it anything but a `number` or `any`?

Comment: @NitzanTomer I try to pass an any! But it only accepts a number. This is the problem. The value can be 3 or "3" or "hello world".

Comment: It does work with `any`: `let a: any = "str"; console.log(isNaN(a));` is fine with the compiler, in fact this is fine as well: `isNaN("str" as any)`

Comment: @NitzanTomer you're right. I tested it now and it works with any. The problem was that my parameter was declared as "string | number". For next time I'll write my actual code instead of simplifying it. Please write it as an answer (to pass any) and I'll accept it.

Comment: @NitzanTomer The same way you find yourself calling parseInt and parseFloat, which explicitly require a string.  Sometimes your data is not in its correct format/type until you put it there.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

I advise you to implement your code differently.
The reasons:

1. It might be short, but it's not easy to understand what's going on
2. Using `isNaN` isn't the best option here: `isNaN("")` returns `false` as well

You better try to convert the value into a number and check if that's `NaN` or not (as @smnbbrv wrote):

```
if (typeof expectedValue === "string" && !Number.isNaN(Number(expectedValue))) {
    expectedValue = Number(expectedValue);
}
```

---

#### Edit

You can pass your value as `any`:

```
isNaN(ctualValue as any)
```

To bypass the compiler check.

Comment: Your question is what's called a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), which is why all the answers/comments here are about your use of `isNaN`. I updated my answer for what you wanted

Comment: Thanks. I changed my code to your suggestion. You're right it was an XY problem. I didn't know that an empty string would return false.

Comment: I refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/175787/351426 as to the validity of isNaN taking more than just a number.

Comment: 1up for `as any`.

Comment: Since `Number("")` is `0`, `isNaN(Number(""))` will *still* return false...

Comment: Passing the value as `any` helped by my compiler wasn't satisfied. I used `isNaN` to prevent NaN from flashing while the data loaded. Passing `isNaN(value as unknown as number)` was the solution. 
In my case, `percentageTotal={isNaN(percentageTotal as unknown as number) ? "0" : percentageTotal}` Having a loader, while data loaded could have solved this as well, but now I am free to display empty charts while the data loads for a nice visual effect. Thank you @NitzanTomer for relieving some TS troubles.

Answer (score 30):

You should not solve it because this is how TypeScript works.

Just cast the input to number first

```
Number("10") // 10
Number("abc") // NaN
```

and then check the result with the isNan function:

```
isNaN(Number("abc"))
```

Comment: It typically suggested to avoid the `Number()`, `String()` and `Boolean()` functions. Probably better to use `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus you are probably talking about `new Number()` which usually one should avoid (because instead of creating literal they create objects) and is deprecated in ES6 if I remember right; however `Number()` does not have any problem. If it does, please clarify that

Comment: Actually, I'm talking about their usage altogether.

Comment: Please, clarify why it is bad. I use it often and I don't have any problems. It's not like I'm telling you are wrong; I really want to know if it is a bad practice to improve my code

Comment: What will `Number('0x11')` and `Number('0b11')` produce?

Comment: What will `Number("123hui")` return?

Comment: `NaN` for both which is right behavior unless you explicitly want to support hexadecimal numbers which is not a subject of this discussion. I've got your point: you have no arguments.

Comment: Actually, `Number('0x11')` produces `17` and `Number('0b11')` produces `3`. Only `Number("123hui")` produces `NaN`. So, is it correct to get `17` from `Number('0x11')` when the string happens to start with `0x`? Or, should it return `NaN`?

Comment: I don't really check if a literal is Nan, I simplified my code. Anyway isNan is supposed to accept any type according to the specification.

Comment: @ScottMarcus doesn't `parseInt('0x11')` also return 17?

Comment: @Paarth yes, but you're never meant to use `parseInt` without a `radix` – `parseInt('0x11') // => 17` vs `parseInt('0x11', 10) // => 0`.

Comment: Tho I still disagree that using `Number` is somehow bad. As with all things, you have to consider your use case and determine which function fulfills those specific criterion – if no such built-in is satisfactory, a custom function is required.

Comment: @Paarth `parseInt()` has a second, optional (but really it should always be used) argument to supply a radix, so that the conversion happens in the correct numeric base.

Comment: It should be noted that parseInt and parseFloat will produce unexpected behaviour when dealing with NaN, for example "2022-13-11" will return 2022, which then is a valid number. Given that `Number("")` also returns 0, are we supposed to check for `typeof string`, `val != ""` AND `isNaN(Number(val))` ?
Is there really no way of sensibly doing this?

Answer (score 3):

As ironically only numbers can be `NaN`, you need to transform strings into numbers first.

A very simple way to do this is the unary plus operator.

So you can do a simple `isNaN(+"10")`.

Keep in mind that thing like `+""`, `+" "` and `+"\n"` are 0!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, only values of type `number` can be `NaN`. So if the static context tells you your value is of type `string` for example, you can be sure that it is not a `NaN`. If you have a value with type `string|number` (which should be avoided btw) you can still decide how you handle this. Strictly speaking, the string value `"foo"` is not `NaN`, as `NaN` is a specific value specified in the IEEE standard for float numbers. But still, in javascript, `isNaN("foo")` will be true, as the function [will coerect the string to a number](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-isnan-number) first, and that coerection results in a `NaN`. Typescript tries to take advantage of types here, it tries to prevent you from using `isNaN` where you should not.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by using parseInt inside your isNaN. The check isNaN will still work if the parseInt returns NaN. And your Typescript error will be solved.

```
if (typeof actualValue === "string" && !isNaN(parseInt(actualValue, 10))) {
  actualValue = +actualValue;
}
```

Comment: I don't like this solution, as it requires "wasting extra CPU cycles", when `isNaN` is in fact perfectly capable of handling non-number types. `isNaN` is not only useful for checking whether the number is "exactly `NaN`", but also whether the object "is not a number". Using `const x = n === undefined || n === null || isNaN(n) ? -1 : n` where `const x = isNaN(n) ? -1 : n` is just a waste of space.

Comment: @diemaus And what do you think `isNaN` function does? It converts that non-numeric value to numeric, which is "wasting extra CPU cycles" as well. This was it's just explicit. Explicit = good.

Answer (score 1):

In the accepted answer, `!Number.isNaN(Number(expectedValue))` still returns true for empty string (`''`) and whitespace strings (`'  '`). And converting these to number will result in `0`.

I'm not a JavaScript developer, and – especially coming from .Net – it looks insane to me as well, but this is what I've done that seems to work:

```js
private static isNumber(value: any): boolean {
  return (typeof value === 'number' && !isNaN(value))
      || ((typeof value === 'string') && value.trim() != '' && !isNaN(Number(value)))
  }
```

If you know a saner solution, be sure to edit this!

```
console.log(isNumber([]));      // false
console.log(isNumber({}));      // false
console.log(isNumber(""));      // false
console.log(isNumber("   "));   // false
console.log(isNumber(" 1  "));  // true <= note
console.log(isNumber(" 1  2")); // false
console.log(isNumber("1"));     // true
console.log(isNumber(1));       // true
```

Answer (score 1):

Passing `isNaN(value as unknown as number)` satisfied my compiler.
In my case, I was using `isNaN()` to prevent "NaN" from flashing while data loaded. This allowed me to pass a `string` into `isNaN()` since the interface expected a string.

Answer (score 0):

Found this answer from Google, and reached my answer from the various answers and comments here; my answer is to use:

```
isNaN(Number(string))
```

This will correctly tell me if the string is a number.

I was previously using parseInt(), but this fails if the string is something like `123abc` as parseInt just discards the letters (useful sometimes, but not here).

**Note:** I'm happy that `Number('')` evaluates to zero, but if your not, this isn't the solution!