# how to use rxjs isNumeric() function?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm new to rxjs but I think it's part of all ng apps and I've read that it has a handy isNumeric() function.  I tried both of the following imports:

```
import 'rxjs/util/isNumeric';
import 'es6/util/isNumeric';
```

Here's some sample code that I tried to hook into this rxjs isNumeric() function:

```
var testString = "100";

//this doesn't compile
var isNumber = isNumeric(testString);

//this fails at runtime
var isNumber = testString.isNumeric();
```

What am I missing with this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This isn't specifically a RxJS thing, but more generally how to import standalone functions from other files.  There's (at least) two ways you can do this.  Since `isNumeric` only has one function, you can import it this way:

```
import {isNumeric} from "rxjs/util/isNumeric"
//
var isNumber = isNumeric(testString)
```

You can also import all the functions in a file at once like this:

```
import * as rxjsNumeric from "rxjs/util/isNumeric"
//
var isNumber = rxjsNumeric.isNumeric(testString)
```

But there's not much benefit to that in this particular case.

**NOTE:** As of RxJS 6, these utility functions are [no longer available](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/commit/70058cd). However, the syntax still works for the general case of importing functions.

Comment: I've noticed that isNumeric("20,000") returns false :(

Comment: @user2010955 presumably the comma is tripping it up

Comment: So rxjs 6 doesn't have this?

Comment: @Helzgate Per [this commit](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/commit/70058cd), it looks like it was hidden in RxJS 6 because the utils weren't meant to be used externally.

Comment: in latest version i use it like this: import { isNumeric } from 'rxjs/internal/util/isNumeric' or replace it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175739/built-in-way-in-javascript-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-number

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/util/isNumeric.ts

For those curious.