# Check if an input string is a positive int/float number

Tags: javascript, string, validation, numbers, decimal

On my webpage there is an input box that should only allow user to enter a positive int/float number (i.e. 1234, 123.4, 12.34, 1.234 should all be allowed).

To make sure the value is valid, I have a function to validate the value before sending it to the server:

```
function isPositiveFloat(s){
    return String(Number(s)) === s && Math.floor(Number(s)) > 0;
}
```

The function works great expect for one scenario:  `isPositiveFloat(1.0)` will return false, as it turns out `Number(1.0)` will convert it to `1`, therefore made the validation failed.

Any suggestions on how should I resolve this issue? Is using regex the only way to go?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: How about `!isNaN(Number(s))`?  Or in fact, just `!isNaN(s)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a (built-in) way in JavaScript to check if a string is a valid number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175739/is-there-a-built-in-way-in-javascript-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-number)

Comment: Thank you! Looks like I overthinking the problem here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use `!isNaN(s)`along with `Number(s)>0`:

```
function isPositiveFloat(s) {
  return !isNaN(s) && Number(s) > 0;
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
function isPositiveFloat(s) {
  return !isNaN(s) && Number(s) > 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onchange="console.log(isPositiveFloat(this.value))" />
```

You can check on the [**MDN reference of `isNaN()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) examples that:

> isNaN('37.37');   // false: "37.37" is converted to the number 37.37 which is not NaN

So as you can see it will be working in your case with float numbers.

Comment: Thank you! It works great! And thanks for the explanation.