# How to identify any string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, random, numbers

An array shows 3 numbers randomly, and I had to write a code that sums the 3 numbers, but the array has a trick to sometimes show a string:

```
[96, ".!asd", 182]
["@#$%", 5, 43]
[64, "bd", 48]
```

I would like to use an "if" that would return "not valid" if there's a string in the array.

```
if (...){
    return not valid
}
```

Please, if there's a way to identify any string, could you tell me the code?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to see if your array contains NaN's

```js
var x = [96, ".!asd", 182]
var y = [96, 1000, 182]
console.log(x.some(isNaN))
console.log(y.some(isNaN))
```

Comment: This is the most efficient check and should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use isNaN to determine if a stirng is a number

```
isNaN('123') //false   
isNaN('Hello') //true
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the object **[`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN)**:

```
if (Number.isNaN(+element_in_array)) return "Not Valid!!"
```

```js
function sum(array) {
  if (array.some((n) => Number.isNaN(+n))) {
    return "Invalid data, at least one element is not a number.";
  }
  
  return array.reduce((a, n) => a + Number(n), 0);
}

console.log(sum([96, ".!asd", 182]))
console.log(sum(["@#$%", 5, 43]))
console.log(sum([64, "bd", 48]))
console.log(sum([64, 44, 48]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `isNaN` function as it is explained here : [Is there a (built-in) way in JavaScript to check if a string is a valid number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175739/is-there-a-built-in-way-in-javascript-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-number)

```
isNaN(123)         // false
isNaN('123')       // false
isNaN('1e10000')   // false (This translates to Infinity, which is a number)
isNaN('foo')       // true
isNaN('10px')      // true
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `NaN` to determine if all elements are numbers by using an unary plus to convert the string to number. If succeed, you get a number for summing, if not then `NaN` is returned and summed. A single `NaN` spoils the result and the result is `NaN`.

```js
function not(fn) {
    return function (v) {
        return !fn(v);
    };
}

function sum(array) {
    return array.reduce((a, b) => +a + +b);
}

console.log([[96, ".!asd", 182], ["@#$%", 5, 43], [64, "bd", 48], [2, 3, 5]].map(sum).filter(not(isNaN)));
```

Answer (score -1):

try using *typeof* to validate wether or not you are dealing with a string.[mdn typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

Answer (score -2):

You can use `if type(x) == str` to check if a variable x is of type String. It is a built-in function. Please refer to official python documentation to know more.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type

Comment: Javascript, not Python