# parseInt is not returning NaN when there is a letter

Tags: javascript

```
parseInt('5aab4') //5
// I expect the output is NaN.
```

My logic fails, due to parseInt. I assume that parseInt always returns NaN, when the input contains a letter?

Comment: *"I assume that parseInt always returns NaN, when the input contains a letter"* - Don't assume, verify: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt  You also may find some responses here useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175739/built-in-way-in-javascript-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-number

Comment: Indeed, from the documentation:  "If parseInt encounters a character that is not a numeral in the specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and returns the integer value parsed up to that point"

Comment: @ScottMarcus. I don't think it's a duplicate. My question is not how parseInt() works rather another option to check if a string only contains a number.

Comment: You make no mention of another option in your question. You say *I assume that parseInt always returns NaN, when the input contains a letter?* which indicates you are asking about how `parseInt()` works. In fact, no where in the entire question do you even use the words *"check if a string only contains a number"*.

Answer (score 3):

No, `parseInt()` allows "garbage" (non-number) characters after some numeric characters. The `parseFloat()` function has the same "feature".

If you want to get a number, you can use `Number("123")` or simply the `+` unary operator. However those accept any JavaScript number, including ones with fractional parts or numbers in scientific notation. But those methods will fail and give `NaN` if the string input is not  a valid numeric constant.

You could do something like

```
if (+someString === Math.floor(+someString))
```

I guess.

*edit* — a comment notes that you'd also want to check the degenerate case of an empty or all-space string too. A simple regular expression (`/^\d+$/`) followed by a sanity check that it's not 200 digits long (amonth possibly other things) is another alternative.

Comment: I have never known why it works that way, but it always has.

Comment: So, do you have another better way, to check if the string only contains a number?

Comment: "I have never known why it works that way, but it always has." [Because that's the specified behavior.](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-parseint-string-radix)

Comment: @JordanRunning yes of course that's true, but it was designed and implemented *before* the language semantics were codified in a specification.

Comment: `+' ' === 0`. JavaScript is *wonderful*.

Comment: @AuxTaco yea good point, I generally just use a regex for checking integers

Comment: As stated this is a "feature" of JS. JS is full of crazyass coercions. See https://github.com/denysdovhan/wtfjs#-examples for a ton of insane examples.

Answer (score -1):

If you were wanting to check `NaN`another way would be to test it with `isNaN()`. 
`isNaN()` will return a boolean giving you a verification for a given input.

```
parseInt('5aab4') //5

isNaN('5aab4') // true
```

Comment: it won't limit the input to just integers however

Comment: But keep in mind that `isNaN('6e23')` and `isNaN(' ')` are false.