# How to compare what the person type? If char equal char do that

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to do a comparison with what the user type (his name - char) with the variable name (char). But idk how can i do that.

```
var nome=document.getElementById("nome").value;
var mat=document.getElementById("mat").value; //Disciplina

if (nome===name){
    alert("Sua média é: "+ resultado);  
} else {
    alert("Error.");
    return;
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<p class="p">Nome do aluno: <input class ="form-control" id="nome" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Preencha seu nome"/></p>
<button type="button" class="" onclick="media()">Calcular</button>
```

Javascript code:

```
function media() {
    var nome=document.getElementById("nome").value;
    var mat=document.getElementById("mat").value; //Disciplina

    if (nome===name){
        alert("Sua média é: "+ resultado);
    } else {
        alert("Error.");
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: *Html*
<p class="p">Nome do aluno: <input class ="form-control" id="nome" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Preencha seu nome"/></p>

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to run this comparison each time the user presses a button on the keyboard?

Comment: No dekajob. Example: Your name is Dejakob. If you type Dekajob in my html site the program continue. But when u type a number, it shows a message "This is not a name". I want to do this comparison.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/mkqownc2/

Comment: The fourth bird, i want to do a comparison if your name is char or not. If your name is equal char (Right!) but if your name is equal a number - int - (Error!)

Comment: When i say char is string.

Comment: You might take a look at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175739/built-in-way-in-javascript-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-number) how you could do that

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to test if the input value is a valid name?Like this?

```
function testName(input) {
  return /^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(input)
}
```

The regexp /^[a-zA-Z]+$/ only match strings combined by char a-z and A-Z.

In your code:

```
function media() {

    var nome=document.getElementById("nome").value;
    var mat=document.getElementById("mat").value; //Disciplina

    if (/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(nome)){
        alert("Sua média é: "+ resultado);

    }

    else{
        alert("Error.");
        return;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes BigLiao, but i started today learning js, i dont know hot to put this in the code.

Comment: This is what i want to do, but with string.

var num = "987238";

if(num.match(/^-{0,1}\d+$/)){
  //valid integer (positive or negative)
}else if(num.match(/^\d+\.\d+$/)){
  //valid float
}else{
  //not valid number
}

Comment: But one more question, if i want to use special character (UTF-8). What is the regex?

Comment: Yes you can use regexp to match special characters.For example, the chinese unicode set is "4E00-9FA5", so the regexp is `/[\u4E00-\u9FA5]/`. But this seems like a new feature, I'm not sure can it work in old browser.