# How do i check if an array contains integar

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, int

I am trying to loop through an array and check if it contains an integar but i cant get it to work and i dont understand why. Do I have to use the map method?

My code is like this:

```
 let words = ['Dog', 'Zebra', 'Fish'];


    for(let i = 0; i <= words.length; i++){

        if(typeof words[i] === String){

            console.log('It does not contain any Numbers')
        }
        else{
            let error = new Error('It does contain Numbers')
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
```

Comment: `typeof "hello world"` is the string `"string"`, not `String`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(Built-in) way in JavaScript to check if a string is a valid number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175739/built-in-way-in-javascript-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-number)

Answer (score 0):

Check the words array:

```
words.includes(int);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not a javascript expert but what about:

```
 isNaN(words[i])
```

instead of the typeof call?

I got this from a similar question here: [(Built-in) way in JavaScript to check if a string is a valid number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175739/built-in-way-in-javascript-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-number)

Answer (score 0):

If you just have to check if any integer there or not in array, you can make use of `some` method:

```js
let words = ['Dog', 'Zebra', 'Fish'];
var result = words.some(val=>isFinite(val));
console.log(result);
```

`some` will return `true` or `false` accordingly. In this case it will be false as no numbers are present in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following in-build javascript function for this

```
isNaN(value) //It will returns true if the variable is not a valid number
```

Example:

```
isNaN('Dog') //it will return true as it is not a number
isNaN('100') //it will false as its a valid number
```

You can do:

```
isNaN(words[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you should check for === "string"
2. Note, that your for loop has to be < instead of <=, otherwise you would iterate it 4 times instead of 3

Your code should look like this:

```js
    let words = ['Dog', 'Zebra', 'Fish'];

    for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
      if (typeof words[i] === "string") {
        console.log('It does not contain any Numbers')
      } else {
        let error = new Error('It does contain Numbers')
        console.log(error)
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my contribution to a possible solution:

```
let arr = ["Susan", "John", "Banana", 32];

// Option 1
arr.map(item => typeof item)

// Option 2
arr.map(item => console.log("Array item: ", item, "is a", typeof item))

// Option 3
arr.map(item => {
    if(typeof item === "string") {
        console.log("Item is a string");
    } else {
        let error = new Error("Item contains numbers")
        console.error(`%c${error}`, "color: red; font-weight: bold" );
    }
})
```