# Discordjs args check if its a word

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

im making a bot to get bitcoin price and also exchange it from discord. I want to check if args[0] it is a number, if not to return and send a message.

```
        if (!args.length){
            return message.channel.send(`${message.author} You need to input arguments, example: -exchange 15000`);
        }


        const url = `https://blockchain.info/tobtc?currency=USD&value=${args[0]}`;

        request(url, (err, res, body) => {
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/175787/6126373

Comment: `isNaN(args[0])` will be true if `args[0]` is NOT a number.. try that

Comment: Maybe `if (isNaN(args[0])) { return message.channel.send('You need to input a number not a  letter'); }`.

Answer (score 0):

- use `args[0]` instead of `args.length`
- if you use `args` with `if(args)` it will return a **Boolean**
- so your code should be like this :

```js
if (!args[0]){
  return message.channel.send(`${message.author} You need to input arguments, example: -exchange 15000`);
}
```