# print the longest word and ignore the numbers

Tags: javascript, nan, longest-substring

i'm trying to print the longest word from a string and to ignore the number,
so even though the number is the longest, it will print the longest word.

```js
let userInput = "print the longest word 3372838236253 without number"; 

function longestWord(userInput) {
    let x = userInput.split(" ");
    let longest = 0;
    let word = null;
    x.forEach(function(x) {
        if (longest < x.length) {
            longest = x.length;
            word = x;
        }
    });
    return word;
}

console.log(longestWord(userInput));
```

Comment: Along with the `longest < x.length` condition, check if `x` is a number. [Check if a string is a valid number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/175739)

Answer (score 1):

Check word to be a number with `isNumeric`

```js
let userInput = "print the longest word 3372838236253 without number"; 

function isNumeric(num){
  return !isNaN(num) && !isNaN(parseFloat(num))
}

function longestWord(userInput) {
    let words = userInput.split(" ");
    let longest = 0;
    let word = null;
    words.forEach(function(w) {
        if (longest < w.length && !isNumeric(w)) {
            longest = w.length;
            word = w;
        }
    });
    return word;
}

console.log(longestWord(userInput));
```

Comment: @orela123 extend your question with examples of good and bad cases