# Discord.js check if message is a number

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

I have a discord bot and I'm trying to figure out a way of knowing if a message is a number. Here's the code I have:

```
if (message.isNumber()){
   //do something
}
```

```
String.prototype.isNumber = function() {
  return /^\d+$/.test(this);
};
```

When I test it, it does absolutely nothing. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Hi welcome to SO ! I think the prototype you added to `String` would only work if the variable is ... a `String`. Checkout my answer to see what other options you have !

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do:

```js
if(isNaN(message.content) return;
else {
  //do something
}
```

If the message is not a number, it would do nothing. Otherwise it would do that what you would like it to do.

Comment: You assume that `message` is an object which has a `content` key - Where did you get this information ? OP does not include it

Comment: I know it, because I am using discord.js as well and you can see it [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=content)

Comment: And he said that it works for him, so I guess it was right.

Comment: Fair enough - didn't know you had contact with him outside of this post . You could include this information in your answer

Answer (score 0):

Since OP does not provide more context about what `message` is, I assume `message` already holds the value that needs to be checked. So I also have to ignore that `message` could be an object coming from Discord.js, and that the value OP wants to check really is located at `message.content`, not `message`. Even if I know Discord.js API, `message` could be something completely different here.

If the value that needs to be checked really is located at `message.content` and does come from Discord.js API, checkout @JannikSchmidtke answer, he might know more about the Discord.js API and the context about this question.

---

### Case A : You want to check if the type of a variable is a number

You can use `typeof` to check the type of it :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

```js
if (typeof message == 'number') { console.log('is a number'); }
if (!(typeof message == 'number')) { console.log('is a not a number'); }
```

---

### Case B : You want to check a variable if it is a valid number

You could use `isNaN` in certain cases. Here a string could be a valid number as well:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN

```js
isNaN(123)         // false, it is a number
isNaN('123')       // false, it is a number
isNaN('1e10000')   // false (This translates to Infinity, which is a number)
isNaN('foo')       // true, it is not a number
isNaN('10px')      // true, is is not a number
```

---

You will also find a very good and complete answere here : [(Built-in) way in JavaScript to check if a string is a valid number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175739/built-in-way-in-javascript-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-number)

Comment: To whom suggested an edit to my answer : OP does not include what `message` actually is so I have to assume `message` is the actual content that needs to be checked. If `message` is an object it will fail because an object is not a number , simple as that.