# Create a new array dynamically whenever there is a number in Input Array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am stuck in a problem. I have user input of array which contains `number` as well as `strings` like:-

```
 3
apple
Lemmon
sugar
2
Ginger
Ice
```

This is the data that I am receiving.
Now I have to manipulate the data as such that. "Whenever it encounters a number it creates a new array with exactly the number values in array".

Desired Output

```
Array1 ["apple", "Lemmon", "sugar"]
Array2 ["Ginger", "ice"]
```

Any Idea will help. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can simply detect if the input is a number and create a new array. There are several ways to do this -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175739/built-in-way-in-javascript-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-number

Comment: Like this array can extend and I want it should go in a new array everytime there is a number encountered.
Can you please suggest one way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you get the info. But this is the first idea I got to quickly solve your issue:

```
function makeArray(...info) {
  stringArray = [];
  i = -1;
  info.forEach(item => {
    console.log(item);
    if (Number(item)) {
      stringArray.push([]);
      i+=1;
    } else stringArray[i].push(item);
  });
  return stringArray;
}

makeArray(3, 'apple', 'Lemmon', 'sugar', 2, 'Ginger', 'Ice');
```

If you log that you get:

```
[ [ 'apple', 'Lemmon', 'sugar' ], [ 'Ginger', 'Ice' ] ]
```

It makes a 2D array. And from there maybe you can use it like that or just sepparate it easily.

Comment: nice solution! just a tip, it would be good to define your variables with `let` -> `let i = -1;` `let stringArray = [];`

Comment: jaja, totally right! For doing it quickly I forgot that, and even left a console.log there. Thanks for pointing it out @buzatto

Comment: that's normal, it happens to all of us. you can always `edit` your answer to fix something or add more context. welcome to the forum!

Comment: Great solution @AlfredoC... That was a great Help.