# Input type number that only accepts divisible by 5. If not, produce an alert error

Tags: javascript, html

my target is to accept only divisible by 5. When I type 6 and it is not divisible by 5, produce an alert error "This number is invalid". How can I make it work? My current work is when it's not divisible by 5, the input type number gets red.

```css
:invalid {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" min="0" max="9000" step="5" />
```

Comment: chk http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want use Pure js you can use this function see if number is divisible by 5 like:

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[data-id="inputnumber"]');
inputs.forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('change', () => {
    if (input.value % 5 !== 0) {
      alert('not valid');
      input.value = 5;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
:invalid {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" min="0" max="9000" step="5" data-id='inputnumber' />
<input type="number" min="0" max="9000" step="5" data-id='inputnumber' />
```

i add a simple reset by 5 if is wrong

---

After comment of OP i changed my snippet to make it work with 2 or more inputs with `data-id`

Comment: Hello, is it okay for me to add a follow-up question? What if I have 2 input type? i have tried it with one and it is perfectly working, however when I'm doing 2 input type with the same IDs it's not working anymore.

Comment: I changed the example to fit your second question :)

Comment: Another idea, if you need to change the number to divide, for example 1 input % 5 and another %6 you can use data attribute for change it :)

Answer (score 2):

If only CSS is the way you want to achieve this without the **alert** and a sibling element, You can do so by introducing an additional p element and only making it visible when the sibling input is invalid like so :-

```css
p{
display:none;
}

input:invalid{
background:red;
}

input:invalid + p {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" min="0" max="9000" step="5" />
<p>This number is invalid</p>
```

Otherwise there are already so many JS ways to do the same which can be found on Stack Overflow.

Comment: If he have more than 1 `p` ?

Comment: Multiple options there. Give `input` a class. and if for all inputs you need just one `p`, change from `+` to `~` , otherwise have separate `p` fields for each input (which usually happens in forms).

Answer (score 0):

You can also catch the invalid value and display you own message. Here you don't have to test the value. To remove the massage again you have to look for either change, keydown, paste or input.

```js
document.forms.test.num.addEventListener('invalid', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById('message').classList.remove('hide');
});

document.forms.test.num.addEventListener('input', e => {
  document.getElementById('message').classList.add('hide');
});

document.forms.test.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
input:invalid {
  background: red;
}

span.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form name="test">
  <input name="num" type="number" min="0" max="9000" step="5" />
  <span id="message" class="hide">This is not a valid number!</span>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<input type="number" name="pax" min="0" max="100" step="5" value="0">
```

Comment: Hello, is it possible when i type 6, the system will automatically gives an alert error "this number is not valid"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175739/built-in-way-in-javascript-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-number