# Regex: extract string after each ":"

Tags: javascript, split

I have string like:

```
"abc:12:toto:tata:titi"
```

and I want to got each string after `":"` with a `split()`, so it will be `"toto"`, `"tata"` and `"titi"` in this case.

Comment: try `str.match(/(?<=:)[a-z]+/g)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And I just want to **got each string** after `:`

If we use [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) combined with [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) we can filter out any part that [is a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175739/built-in-way-in-javascript-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-number).

To remove the first one, I've added a [`splice(1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```js
const input = 'abc:12:toto:tata:titi';
const res = input.split(':').slice(1).filter(n => isNaN(n) && isNaN(parseFloat(n)));

console.log(res);
```

```json
[
  "toto",
  "tata",
  "titi"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```
const str = 'abc:12:toto:tata:titi';

const words = str.split(':');
console.log(words);
```

Output:

`Array(5) [ "abc", "12", "toto", "tata", "titi" ]`

RegEx is not necessary, since your delimiter is constant and vary simple.

If you literally only want to get the alpha strings, immediately following a colon (":"), then use:

```
const str = 'abc:12:toto:tata:titi';

const filteredWords = words.slice(1).filter(word => !isNaN(parseInt(word)));
console.log(filteredWords)
```

Output:

`Array(5) [ "toto", "tata", "titi" ]`

Comment: And if I just want "toto", "tata", "titi" without "abc" and "12"
How can I do it ?

Comment: If you simply want to skip over the first two items, you can slice the `words` list: `console.log(words.slice(2))`. [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) will return a new array with only the items: "toto", "tata", "titi" (but will not mutate the original `words` array).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the colon delimited values would always be either pure numbers or pure letter words:

```js
var input = "abc:12:toto:tata:titi";
var matches = input.replace(/:\d+/g, "").split(":");
matches.shift();
console.log(matches);
```

The regex replacement on `:\d+` removes number elements.  Then we split on colon, and shift off the first element, which can't be a match as it is not preceded by a colon.