# Having trouble debugging JavaScript, regarding Booleans and IsInteger()

Tags: javascript, html

Could someone explain why this code behaves incorrectly. My aim to to have a form that suppresses the submission if the name is not entered, or if a non signed integer is inputted for the age. I have logged the isInteger and more than zero comparisons and they both appear false so I cannot understand why the 'alert("Please enter a valid age.");' is not being executed in the OR statement.

I hope I haven't missed something obvious as I have trying to debug this for an hour now.

Any help would be appreciated

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>JavaScript Practice</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    input {
      display: block;
      margin-bottom: 1em;
    }
    
    label {
      float: left;
      width: 5em;
      padding-right: 1em;
      text-align: right;
    }
    
    #submit {
      margin-left: 7em;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    function validateForm() {
      if (document.forms[0].userName.value == "") {
        alert("Name field cannot be empty.");
        return false;
      }
      console.log(Number.isInteger(document.forms[0].userAge.value));
      console.log(document.forms[0].userAge.value < 0;
        if (!Number.isInteger(document.forms[0].userAge.value) ||
          document.forms[0].userAge.value < 0) {
          alert("Please enter a valid age.");
          return false;
        }
        if (document.forms[0].userAge.value < 18) {
          alert("Age is less than 18. You are not an adult.");
          return false;
        } // end if
        alert("Name and Age are valid.");
        return true;
      } // end function validateForm
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>JavaScript Form Handling</h1>
  <form method="post" action="http://webdevbasics.net/scripts/demo.php" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
    <label for="userName">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName">
    <label for="userAge">Age:</label>
    <input type="text" name="userAge" id="userAge">
    <input type="submit" value="Send information" id="submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: why don't u use a [required attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required) ?

Answer (score 1):

Tried running the code in the browser.

I've got the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list  index.html:31:59
```

The issue was in line 31 where `)` was missing:

```
console.log(document.forms[0].userAge.value < 0);
```

After this fix I was getting `Please enter a valid age.` for any age.

The issue was in [`Number.isInteger()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger), which checks for an argument being an integer and always returns `false` because `userAge.value` is a string.

The check you need here is `if the string is a valid number`, you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/175787/14596856) for all the details, but one suggested method is to use [`parseInt(string, radix)` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseInt) (`radix` argument is optional but it's safer to specify 10):

```
const ageInt = Number.parseInt(document.forms[0].userAge.value, 10);
```

`parseInt` converts a string to a number, `ageInt` will be `NaN` if `userAge.value` is a string which is not a valid number.

So using `ageInt` and `Number.isNaN()` check for `NaN` the condition can be rewritten as:

```
const ageInt = Number.parseInt(document.forms[0].userAge.value, 10);
console.log(ageInt);
console.log(ageInt < 0);
if (Number.isNaN(ageInt) || ageInt < 0) {
    alert("Please enter a valid age.");
    return false;
}
```

You can find the whole updated code bellow:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>JavaScript Practice</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        input {
            display: block;
            margin-bottom: 1em;
        }

        label {
            float: left;
            width: 5em;
            padding-right: 1em;
            text-align: right;
        }

        #submit {
            margin-left: 7em;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function validateForm() {
            if (document.forms[0].userName.value == "") {
                alert("Name field cannot be empty.");
                return false;
            }
            const ageInt = Number.parseInt(document.forms[0].userAge.value, 10);
            console.log(ageInt);
            console.log(ageInt < 0);
            if (Number.isNaN(ageInt) || ageInt < 0) {
                alert("Please enter a valid age.");
                return false;
            }
            if (ageInt < 18) {
                alert("Age is less than 18. You are not an adult.");
                return false;
            } // end if
            alert("Name and Age are valid.");
            return true;
        } // end function validateForm
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>JavaScript Form Handling</h1>
    <form method="post" action="http://webdevbasics.net/scripts/demo.php" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
        <label for="userName">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName">
        <label for="userAge">Age:</label>
        <input type="text" name="userAge" id="userAge">
        <input type="submit" value="Send information" id="submit">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I see what you mean now. Thanks for the help!