# How to detect that the parseFloat() stopped on "other" character?

Tags: javascript, webforms

For getting the float value from the webform (client-side event), I do use the code like:

```
var price = parseFloat(s.GetText());
if (!isNaN(price)) {
    // calculate the related values
}
```

It works fine when the user enters a number (correctly). The `isNaN()` works detects fine also the situation when the user types a string instead of a number (that is, when the first character does not belong to a number).

When the user types the value like `5 x`, the 5 is converted correctly because the parser stops on `x`, and ignores the existence of the `x`. So, the unwanted string after the number is not detected. However, storing the field content `5 x` into the database fails -- because the other code of the web page parses the value differently, and it requires it to be a number and nothing more.

How would you implement the check?

Comment: Stringify the parsed number and check it matches the inputted string?

Comment: @spender - That'll break on lots of things though. Extra leading zeros on the input, the string going to scientific notation, ...

Comment: maybe you'll find lots of inspiration from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175739/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-number

Comment: For this reason, I don't use `parseFloat` nearly ever. I have a `parseNumber` function that uses a conversion using the full string (e.g., `+str` or `Number(str)`, handling the case where `""` would be considered `0` beforehand: `const parseNumber = (str) => str ? +str : NaN;` [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994839/why-does-string-to-number-comparison-work-in-javascript/28994875#28994875) (one of mine) describes various ways you can parse strings to numbers.