# Assertion error on number of digits in a string

Tags: javascript

My code works for some input but for an input like this:
('This'+ 'painting'+ '1845 and 1910') I get an error: AssertionError 7 == 8. I can solve it using regular expression but I don't know what I'm doing wrong in this. Thanks for answering.

```
import assert from "assert";

function countDigits(text){
    
    let num = text.split('');
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i=0; i<num.length; i++){
        if (Number(num[i])) {
            sum += 1;}}
    return sum
}

assert.equal(countDigits('This'
 + 'painting'
 + '1845 and 1910'), 8);
```

Comment: Where is this `AssertionError` coming from?

Comment: Evaluating `console.log(countDigits("0000000000"));` might give you a clue.

Comment: In other words, be wary of making assumptions about truthiness in JS.

Comment: You know that `0` is falsey, right?

Comment: They do now....

Comment: it's not working when ```Number(num[i]) = 0```

Comment: @Wyck I didn't know that. what can I do in this case?

Comment: Check to see if it's a digit.

Comment: `Number()` is not a logical test to determine whether or not something is a number.  Consider reading [How can I check if a string is a valid number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175739/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Number(num[i])` will include `"0"` conversion to a number but in Javascript's if condition, it will be falsy

```js
if(Number("0")) {
  console.log('true') //you're expecting this because it's a number
} else {
  console.log('false') //but in fact, it returns this because 0 is falsy
}
```

In that case, I'd suggest you use `isNaN(num[i])`

```js
function countDigits(text) {

  let num = text.split('');
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
    //num[i] = " " will be considered a number, so we need to check it as well
    if (num[i] !== " " && !isNaN(num[i])) {
      sum += 1;
    }
  }
  return sum
}

console.log(countDigits('This' +
  'painting' +
  '1845 and 1910'))
```