# 146 Uncaught ReferenceError: temperature is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.cityOptions

Tags: javascript

I am a new one here and currently learning Java. Have faced an issue while building a simple page where h1 should be updated depending on the result in let temperature = prompt("What temperature is it?");

Although when I try to add temperature here

```
let city = prompt("What city do you live in?");
        if (currentTemperature()) {
          updateHeading(`Currently ${temperature} in ${city}`);
```

In console it says *html:146 Uncaught ReferenceError: temperature is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.cityOptions*

How can I fix that?

Here is the full code

```
<script>
      function updateHeading(newHeading) {
        let heading = document.querySelector("h1");
        heading.innerHTML = newHeading;
      }

      function currentTemperature() {
        let temperature = prompt("What temperature is it?");
        return temperature >= 0;
      }

      function cityOptions() {
        let city = prompt("What city do you live in?");
        if (currentTemperature()) {
          updateHeading(`Currently ${temperature} in ${city}`);
        } else {
          updateHeading(`Currently ${temperature} in ${city}`);
        }
      }

      let changeCityButton = document.querySelector("button");
      changeCityButton.addEventListener("click", cityOptions);
    </script>
```

Comment: _"...and currently learning Java."_ - [JavaScript is not Java](http://javascriptisnotjava.com)

Comment: Why do you compare (a string) with `>= 0;` and return the result of that expression when you want the temperature?

Comment: Why is there an `if ... else ...` in `cityOptions()` when both branches do the exact same thing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0):

Your `let temperature` is only visible inside the function it is in.

I think you meant to test the temperature entered is a number:

[How can I check if a string is a valid number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175739/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-number)

```js
const isNumeric = str => /^-?\d+$/.test(str);

function updateHeading(newHeading) {
  let heading = document.querySelector("h1");
  heading.innerHTML = newHeading;
}

function currentTemperature() {
  let temperature = prompt("What temperature is it?");
  return isNumeric(temperature) ? temperature : null; // only return the temperature if a number
}

function cityOptions() {
  let city = prompt("What city do you live in?");
  let temperature = currentTemperature()
  if (city && temperature !== null) {
    updateHeading(`Currently ${temperature}C in ${city}`);
  }
}

let changeCityButton = document.querySelector("button");
changeCityButton.addEventListener("click", cityOptions);
```

```html
<h1></h1>
<button type="button">Click</button>
```